# How can I register ACEDAO.DLL using a Setup and without installing Office?

Tags: dll, vb6, ms-access-2007

I am working on a program which uses Access 97 databases (with DAO350.DLL). My goal is to make this program use Access 2007 (and so ACEDAO.DLL) and then deploy the new version on several computers (win7 64bits sp1 without office at all), which don't necessarily had the previous version of the program installed.

I made a new setup by modifying the former setup of the program (created with Package & Deployment Wizard). I thought it was a good idea since PDW doesn't find all the dependencies of the program (former setup contained added-by-hand files) and so I added ACEDAO.DLL.

The setup is made of : Setup.exe, Setup.Lst (which list all files to install and their properties) and a bunch of .CAB archives that contain the files to install.
The line of Setup.Lst concerning ACEDAO is the following :

```
File97=@ACEDAO.dll,$(CommonFiles)\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\,$(DLLSelfRegister),$(Shared),08/21/11 04:52:00 PM,573440,12.0.6650.5000
```

When I execute Setup on an other pc, I get this error :

> ACEDAO.DLL was loaded but entry point for DLLRegisterServer was not
>   found

I learned afterwards that ACEDAO does not contain DLLRegisterServer function, therefore it couldn't work.

Moreover, ACEDAO needs MSO.dll. When I add MSO to the Setup, this one keeps loading the last file (VB6FR.DLL) from [Bootstrap Files] section of the .Lst file forever :
[Traitement de VB6FR.DLL (9/9)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeAOr.png)
My questions are :

1. What can I do to register ACEDAO using the setup ?
2. Any idea why the setup stops when I add MSO.dll ?

---

I apologize for the grammar quality, English isn't my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing/adding DLLs manually is not going to work, there is a large tree of additional file dependencies involved - for example the COM libraries that wrap ACEDAO.DLL driver.

You need to include the correct redistributable which is *probably*:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Your installer will need to run this to install all the files & prerequisites.

Comment: I should have thought about this, I'll check it immediately ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: I used the 2007 redistributable, and it worked perfectly. Thank you again !